# Foreground style of disabled gridview in a listview does not change

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I'm trying to change the foreground of a disabled gridview in WPF.
My xaml looks like this:

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Lote_Entrada_Viscera.Detalle_Entrada_Viscera}" IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Black">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completo}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completo}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle2}">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Producto" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Producto}">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" Width="250"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Cantidad Lote" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cantidad_Lote}" Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Procesados" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Capturadas}" Width="75"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Por Procesar" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Por_Procesar, StringFormat={}{0:#}}"></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

All the answers i have seen point that the trigger on IsEnabled should work, but it maintains the default gray color. I know the trigger works cause i tested changing the background and it worked. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Please take into consideration that I am using mahapps styles.

Comment: looking at your code, in the first line you set the foreground to black, and when it is disabled it is also set to black, is this correct? you want to change the color of it, but it is set to the same color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Brush` with an `x:Key` of "GrayNormalBrush" to `<ListView.Resources>`:

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Lote_Entrada_Viscera.Detalle_Entrada_Viscera}" IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Black">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayNormalBrush" Color="Black" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completo}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        ...
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```